# Can I call React Hook inside a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to change a `state` using `React Hook` **and also** redirect to a new page with passing the changed state to other component after clicking a Button. So I did:

```
const MovieCard = (props) => {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState({})
  
  function handleClick(movie) {
    setMovie(movie)
    props.history.push({
       pathname: '/otherPage',
       data: movie
    })
  }
  
  return(
     ...
       <Button onClick={() => handleClick(props.movie)} />
     ...
  )
}
```

But Hook didn't update the state. Because based on [React Hook docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), it would works like this:

```
<Button onClick={() => setMovie(props.movie)} />
```

Is it possible to call a hook inside a function or there is any way to do it?

Comment: If you've moved to another page, how do you know whether the state has changed?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to achieve something weird. Did you mean you want to update something in the parent component? You are navigating to another page, then why you want to set the state here?. Can you update the question with more details

Comment: @jonrsharpe I miss something, I already add it to make it clear

Comment: @AkhilAravind I miss something, I already add it to make it clear

Comment: Why don't you just use the value that was passed to the callback, instead of the value from the state? Note that what you've posted should work, because you've shadowed the state with the parameter anyway.

Comment: @AlifRamdani in this case, why you want to update the state and move to another component, just pass the values to other components. Why dont you use `props.history.push({
       pathname: '/otherPage',
       data: props.movie
    })` in here

Comment: I was fixated on implementing React Hook. Thanks, I should directly pass the parameter to the other page. BUT still, what if I want to let's say return an HTML block after update the state using a hook?

Comment: update an html block means update the dom, right ?. if you update state, the component will update the dom automatically

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do what you are doing, however by changing to another page you are clearing the state that was stored on that component. You either need to not redirect (which I'm assuming you don't want to do) or you need to pass on that state to the other component you are redirecting to.

Comment: I'm sorry there is a miss information on my question and I already updated it. Please check it again.

Comment: I would go with what jonrsharpe said above. Just pass the data along the history instead of trying to make it into a state. You should be able to get it out of there.